MMpose inferencer not working for MP4 files
I'm trying to use MMPose to find the keypoints in 3d space of individuals in a video. The code I'm using (which has worked before in 2d) is:
from mmpose.apis import MMPoseInferencer
from pathlib import Path
import os

data_folder = Path("x/videos")
for filename in os.listdir(data_folder):
    if not filename.endswith('.mp4'):
        continue
    img_path = os.path.join(data_folder, filename)

    inferencer = MMPoseInferencer(pose3d="human3d")

    result_generator = inferencer(img_path, out_dir='output')

Whenever I try and access the results_generator (like results = [result for result in result_generator]), I get a segfault, which I guess is because there's nothing in result_generator. I would also like for there to be visualisations and data in the output folder, which is empty. Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

show us what you call a "segfault". not every "bad" behavior by a program is a segfault. I find it unlikely that anything segfaults here. [mre]

MMPoseInferrer outputs an iterator, and you need to use next(result) to extract the results from it.
#Make key point predictions
result = inferencer(frame_rgb)
#Output key point results (can be processed or saved as needed)
print(next(result))


I believe OP is aware of this, which is why they tried to use a list comprehension to draw all the items out of the result_generator.
